# Angular translate and ui router

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to translate a multistep form with angular translate and for routing, i'm using ui-router .
everything works fine except one thing .
here is my code **:

translate**

```
.config(function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'App/i18n/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('ir');
})
```

**en.json and ir.json**

```
{
        "wizardForm":{
       "stepOne":{
            "LABEL": "ثبت متقاضی",
            "NATIONALCODE": "کد ملی",
            "NAME": "نام",
            "FATHERNAME": "نام پدر",
            "GENDER": "جنسیت",
       }
}
```

en.json////////

```
{
"wizardForm":{
    "stepOne":{
        "LABEL": "Register Requester",
        "NATIONALCODE": "National Code",
        "NAME": "NAme",
        "FATHERNAME": "Father Name",
        "GENDER": "Gender",

    }
}
```

**html**

```
            <label translate="wizardForm.stepOne.NATIONALCODE">

            </label>
```

translate works fine in other sections but not in form ? am i missing something ?

Comment: Is the name of the json files correct? Shouldn't "ir.json" be "locale-ir.json"? Just a quick guess...

Comment: yes, because other section use ir.json

Comment: But above you are specifying "prefix: 'App/i18n/locale-". That's why I thought it is perhaps needed to remove the 'locale-' from the prefix or add 'locale-' to the file name? So that the System can find the ir.json file or the locale-ir.json file.

Comment: should i use this in every controller : 
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
    };

Comment: No. Definitely not. I cannot try it out here unfortunately but I would try to first simplify your code to hunt down the bug and than re-add complexity. Try to translate without the static file helper, try to get rid of the hierarchy in the json files for debugging and so on... Or create a plunkr we can have a look at. Are you sure your files are at the correct place and have the right names? Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67855/discussion-between-timtos-and-user3642164).

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid. It should be

```
{
    "wizardForm": {
        "stepOne": {
            "LABEL": "Register Requester",
            "NATIONALCODE": "National Code",
            "NAME": "NAme",
            "FATHERNAME": "Father Name",
            "GENDER": "Gender"
        }
    }
}
```

and not

```
{
"wizardForm":{
    "stepOne":{
        "LABEL": "Register Requester",
        "NATIONALCODE": "National Code",
        "NAME": "NAme",
        "FATHERNAME": "Father Name",
        "GENDER": "Gender",

    }
}
```

You are missing one '}' and have one ',' too much.

Try your json here: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Does that help?

Comment: unfortunately no , the problem is, i defined a parent controller in line 1 , and some field can access to controller and some field can't.  you have an idea ?